# Python: Checking file names in a directory one by one

Tags: python-3.x

I am asking for user input of a name, and I want to search in the directory of the file with the code whether a file exists that is called the same thing as the inputted name, if yes, then the program asks for a new name, if not, then it will create a file with that name. I am struggling because the code I have written only checks the first file in the directory and doesn't continue with the rest. 
The code that I am having the problem with looks something like this:

```
import os
Name = input("Please enter name for new file")
if Name in os.listdir():
    print("Sorry this name already exists, please choose another one")
    break
else:
    NewFile = open("Name" + ".txt", "w+")
    break
```

Comment: If you're creating a file with `.txt` as the extension, you'd probably also want to check for a file with that extension (you're not doing that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob`:

```
import glob
existing = glob.glob('*.txt')
name = '{}.txt'.format(input("Please enter name for new file"))
if name in existing:
    print("Sorry this name already exists, please choose another one")
else:
    newfile = open(name, "w+")
```